# Extracting data from strings when included in a list

Tags: pandas, list, iteration, nan, string-parsing

I am trying to order geographical information contained in 4 columns of a Pandas DataFrame, so that administrative subdivisions of the same kind are consistently stored in the same column.

I have built 5 lists of strings containing information about 5 geographical levels I would like to store.

I have tried to populated consistent columns comparing the original 4 inconsistent columns against my 5 consistent lists, but the presence of nan values in the original columns is either triggering errors in my code or returning too many nans in the result columns. Below I provide a minimum code example.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame (np.array([['nan', 'Rome', 'Civitavecchia'],
                             ['Asti', 'nan', 'Piedmont'],
                             ['Bozen', 'Sudtirol', 'nan']]),
 columns=['a','b','c'])


town = ['Civitavecchia']
province = ['Rome', 'Asti', 'Bozen']
region = ['Piedmont', 'Sudtirol']

#first attempt returns a ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups:
df['a'].str.extractall ('|'.join(town))#

#second attempt:
#this only yields two out of six not-nan results expected

df['geo1'] = np.where(df.a.isin(town), df.a, np.nan)
df['geo1'] = np.where(df.b.isin(town), df.b, np.nan)
df['geo1'] = np.where(df.c.isin(town), df.c, np.nan)

df['geo2'] = np.where(df.a.isin(province), df.a, np.nan)
df['geo2'] = np.where(df.b.isin(province), df.b, np.nan)
df['geo2'] = np.where(df.c.isin(province), df.c, np.nan)

df['geo3'] = np.where(df.a.isin(region), df.a, np.nan)
df['geo3'] = np.where(df.b.isin(region), df.b, np.nan)
df['geo3'] = np.where(df.c.isin(region), df.c, np.nan)


dftarget = pd.DataFrame (np.array([['Civitavecchia', 'Rome', 'nan'],
                             ['nan', 'Asti', 'Piedmont'],
                             ['nan', 'Bozen', 'Sudtirol']]),
 columns=['geo1','geo2','geo3'])
```

The output I am aiming for is described in dftarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method, using f-string formatting.   You need the parenthesis inside to define your capture group.   Without the inner paranthensis you get the no capture group defined error.

```
df['c'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(town)})')
```

Output:

```
               0
0  Civitavecchia
1            NaN
2            NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can stack the data, map it, and pivot:

```
# create a common mapping
d = {}
for t in town: d[t] = 'geo1'
for p in province: d[p] = 'geo2'
for r in region: d[r] = 'geo3'    

# stack data for one-go map
a = (df.stack().to_frame(name='data')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    )

# return data
a.dropna().pivot(values='data', columns='col')
```

Output:

```
col           geo1   geo2      geo3
0    Civitavecchia   Rome       NaN
1              NaN   Asti  Piedmont
2              NaN  Bozen  Sudtirol
```

Comment: I have tried to run this, but it returns an error. Should the common mapping be used in the stacking of df?